# Web Site for Desktop and Mobile

Tags: php, html, css, web, mobile-website

How to design a Web Site that will fit to Mobile and Desktop both, Is there any guide line to do in HTML 4 and CSS 2

Comment: Have you tried googling "responsive web design"?

Comment: @Amber: I don't think it's intuitive for someone who has no experience  in web development to search for "responsive web design" if he asks himself how to design a website for both mobile and desktop...

Comment: @Jaro sure, which is why I was suggesting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of articles and tutorials and frameworks which you can use. No holy grail here because each website is different.

Some interesting articles in the topic:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/

http://smashingmagazine.com/tag/responsive-design/

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Frameworks, tools you can use:

http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile

http://gridpak.com/

http://responsive.gs/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need to develop from scratch, rather than using frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

You'd want to look into [responsive frameworks](http://speckyboy.com/2011/11/17/15-responsive-css-frameworks-worth-considering/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop from scratch as you pointed out in the comments, this will help you a lot:

[Article on responsive web design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design)